# Trying to get away from with_items

Tags: ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that has three tasks:

1. Get an SSO token
2. Perform an operation against a list of hosts stated using with_items
3. Revoke the SSO token

The playbook uses **hosts: localhost**
It only processes one host at a time which is to be expected when using with_items.

Each operation takes 1 min times 225 hosts. I'd like to speed this up. If I get away from with_items, it will attempt to get one SSO token per host, which I don't want. How can I get one token and use that one token multiple times AND operate on more than one host at a time?

Here is my YML:

```yaml
---
- name: Start VMs playbook
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars_files: ../vars/site_vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Obtain SSO token with using username/password credentials
      ovirt_auth:
        url: https://rhevm.mgmt.local/ovirt-engine/api
        username: admin@internal
        password: "{{ ADMIN_PASS }}"

    - name: Start virtual machines
      ovirt_vm:
        auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
        state: running
        name: "{{ item.split('.') | first }}"
        template: "template{{ hostvars[item]['cluster_name'][-1] }}"
        cluster: "{{ hostvars[item]['cluster_name'] }}"
      with_items: "{{ groups['virtual_machines'] }}"

    - name: Wait 10 minutes for VMs to setup the IPs using cloud init
      shell: sleep 600

    - name: Revoke the SSO token
      ovirt_auth:
        state: absent
        ovirt_auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
```

Comment: At first glance, and aside from your question `Wait 10 minutes for VMs to setup the IPs using cloud init` > isn't this quite random? Isn't there a [`wait_for`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) that you could use that wouldn't make you wait blindly?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#running-on-a-single-machine-with-run-once

Answer (score 2):

You do have multiple solutions here, but the one that would probably simplify your workflow the most would be to change your `hosts` target and only then [delegate](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegating-tasks) the tasks to *localhost* to replace your loop.

This way, you can use the [`free` strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#selecting-a-strategy) to run the tasks across all hosts simultaneously.
This way of working would also allow you to simplify the constructs like `{{ hostvars[item]['...'] }}` that you are forcing yourself into with a loop.

Then for the token generation and revocation, externalise them in other plays of the same playbook.

So, something like (I oversimplified the playbook for brevity):

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Obtain SSO token with using username/password credentials
      ovirt_auth:
        url: https://rhevm.mgmt.local/ovirt-engine/api
        username: admin@internal
        password: "{{ ADMIN_PASS }}"
      register: sso

- hosts: virtual_machines
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  strategy: free

  tasks:
    - name: Start virtual machines
      ovirt_vm:
        auth: "{{ hostvars.localhost.sso.ovirt_auth }}"
        state: running
        name: "{{ inventory_hostname.split('.') | first }}"
        template: "template{{ cluster_name[-1] }}"
        cluster: "{{ cluster_name }}"
      delegate_to: localhost

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Revoke the SSO token
      ovirt_auth:
        state: absent
        ovirt_auth: "{{ sso.ovirt_auth }}"
```

---

Another possibility is to run in a loop, as you are doing currently, but make your tasks run [asynchronously](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0).

Something like (untested):

```yaml
- ovirt_vm:
    auth: "{{ ovirt_auth }}"
    state: running
    name: "{{ item.split('.') | first }}"
    template: "template{{ hostvars[item]['cluster_name'][-1] }}"
    cluster: "{{ hostvars[item]['cluster_name'] }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['virtual_machines'] }}"
  async: 45
  poll: 0
  register: start_vm

- async_status:
    jid: "{{ item.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 100
  delay: 10
  loop: "{{ start_vm.results }}"
```

Comment: I wound up using your second suggestion (using async). Reduced the time my original script took from 36.5 minutes to 2.5 minutes. :-)